# Find some real matrix $X$ and $Y$ both $2\times2$ none of which be equal to zero, and $XX+YY=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find some matrix $X$ and $Y$ both in $\mathcal{M}_{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$ none of which be equal to zero, for which  $XX+YY=0$.
If anybody can help me, thank's a lot and excuse me for my bad english

Comment: What do you mean "none of which be equal to zero"? Does this refer to the elements of the matrices, or to their determinants (this can be done quite easily with $X, Y$ non-singular) or to the matrices as a whole?

Comment: Hi Mark, I mean elements of the matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use $X=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $Y=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ for which you have $XX \neq 0$ and $YY \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you math, your aswer help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: in linear algebra it is common to define $$\mathbb C=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}|a,b\in\mathbb R\right\}.$$
One then identifies $a+i\cdot b$ with $\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$. Knowing that $i^2=-1$, you should now be able to find such matrices for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Comment: It has the drawback that $X^2=Y^2=0$.

Comment: @Bernard True. It is, however, incredibly simple. The three other answers here all point to the same two matrices, though. That's a bit boring, isn't it?

Comment: @Arthur OK, I tried to find a less boring example.

Comment: @Arthur: I guess we all started from the matrix construction of $\mathbf C$. This is natural, given the equation $X2+Y^2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $X=I_2\,$ and $\,Y=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $X^2=I_2\,$ and $\,Y^2=-I_2$.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish a different example (see comments above), then consider
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 \\  3 & 4\end{pmatrix}, \quad Y=\sqrt{15}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \frac{2}{3} \\  -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $X^2=-Y^2=\begin{pmatrix} -5 & -10 \\  15 & 10\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Hi Professor Dietrich in the beginning of the problem I was trying to find the single matrix Y and taking arbitrarily the values for the elements of the matrix X, but i could not find a Y that when it multiply Y^{2} and Sum in the  XX+YY=0 satisfie the equation.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can start with an arbitrary matrix for $X$, and then you will see why or why not there is a $Y$ with $X^2+Y^2=0$, e.g. with $X=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$ there is no such real matrix $Y$ (but a complex one, of course).

Comment: Professor, I was no trying with a Complex matrix before because in the problem says only (\mathbb{R}) Real Matrices.  But anyway it be helpful for create a algebraic system for find those matrices :)

Answer (score 0):

We can solve the equation (1): $X^2+Y^2=0$ in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Proposition: We consider $Y$ that does not satisfy

a) $spectrum(Y)=\{\lambda,\lambda\}$ where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and $Y$ non-diagonalizable.

b) $spectrum(Y)=\{\lambda,\mu\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ where $|\lambda|\not=|\mu|$.

Then the equation in $X$: $X^2=-Y^2$ has solutions.

Corollary: Let $Y$ be a generic real matrix. If $Y$ has real eigenvalues, then there are no solutions in $X$. Otherwise, there are exactly $2$ solutions in $X$.

Proof of Proposition:  Let $Z\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$. Note that $Z$ is not a square iff i) $Z$ is similar to $\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&1\\0&\alpha\end{pmatrix}$ where $\alpha\leq 0$ OR ii) $\det(Z)<0$ OR iii) $Z$ is similar to $diag(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha<\beta\leq 0$.

Here $Z$ plays the role of $-Y^2$. Case ii) is impossible. Case i) is associated to condition a) and Case iii) is associated to condition b).

EDIT. I explain the second part of Corollary. A real generic matrix that has not a real spectrum is similar to a matrix of the form: $Y=\lambda Rot(\theta)$ where $\lambda,\theta$ are generic real numbers. Then $X^2=-Y^2=\lambda^2Rot(2\theta+\pi)$. Since $X$ is real, there are $2$ (and not $4$) solutions: $X=\pm \lambda Rot(\theta+\pi/2)$.

Comment: Wow great work, thank you professor for the help!

Comment: @ Paul Marrero , if you think that is a great work, then upvote my post.